# Highchart completely loaded after animation event

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there an event that can be triggered for a highchart which can show when a chart has been completely loaded with animation?

I have tried with `load` but it is triggered before the start of the animation.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mdj99nw/1/)

Thanks!

Comment: There is not... You'll need to dig up your own solution.

Comment: @Deep3015 the Highcharts documentation has changed since 3 years. The [animation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.animation) property enables or disables the initial animation when a series is displayed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible. You need to rely on `afterAnimate` [Highcharts property](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.afterAnimate).

[Here is the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maximelafarie/2mdj99nw/2/).